# Activate Electron app on MacOS using Cmd+tab

Tags: macos, electron

In my Electron app on MacOS I can get the app to display the main window if the icon in the dock is clicked using the `activate` event:

```
app.on('activate', () => {

    log.info('activate')
    win.show()
})
```

Which event to I need to use to display the main window when the user uses **Cmd+tab** to activate the app? The `activate` event is not being fired. The behaviour I'm looking for is like GitHub Desktop where using **Cmd+tab** to select the app will open the main window if it's not visible.

Comment: That's not standard behavior for macOS. Look at an app like Apple's Messages: if the window is closed, it will not be re-opened when you CMD-Tab to the app. Same for an Electron app like Slack. You should instead provide `CMD-1`-like keyboard shortcuts under the Window menu to re-open the window.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate that but I wasn't asking for standard behaviour -- I was asking to open the main window when Cmd+tab ing to the app -- like GitHub Desktop (also an Electron app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the GitHub Desktop example, it seems like they customize this behaviour by hijacking their BrowserWindow's `close` event.

In [`app/src/main-process/app-window.ts`](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/6f950eca2734efedce5f9013292430f93f939566/app/src/main-process/app-window.ts#L75-L82):

```js
    if (__DARWIN__) {
      this.window.on('close', e => {
        if (!quitting) {
          e.preventDefault()
          Menu.sendActionToFirstResponder('hide:')
        }
      })
    }
```

After preventing the window from closing, `Menu.sendActionToFirstResponder('hide:')` will hide the entire application instead of doing anything to the window itself. Now, tabbing into the app (as is tabbing into any app hidden with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on macOS) will now reveal it.

Note that you should probably add handlers to ensure that the app closes when you're trying to actually quit, as well. From the same file on the GitHub Desktop repo *(not sure what triggers the IPC event, but just doing `before-quit` works fine to begin with)*:

```js
    let quitting = false
    app.on('before-quit', () => {
      quitting = true
    })

    ipcMain.on('will-quit', (event: Electron.IpcMainEvent) => {
      quitting = true
      event.returnValue = true
    })
```

See a [minimal reproduction Gist](https://gist.github.com/0e484bced996b94c5f94b81a0cc97d71) openable with [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle).

Comment: Hi @Erick - thanks for the help + the clear explanation and the Electron Fiddle!

Comment: Thanks indeed @Erick. I also have a follow up: Is there any event fired (or other way to know) when the app is revealed after a period of being hidden on macOS? I ask because we want to do the exact same thing dmid did, but we also want to restore any minimized windows upon the app being revealed. But I don't see any `app.on('reveal', ...)` or anything like that. Let me know if that's worth another question.

Comment: Off the top of my head: `win.on('show')` handler should trigger when you reveal a window this way. If your other windows are minimized to the dock, you could add a listener to each window like so: `win.on('show', () => { BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().forEach(w => w.restore())})`

Comment: @CemSchemel I believe what you are looking for is `app.on('did-become-active', ...)`, which is fired whenever the app is switched to. See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#event-did-become-active-macos 

I use this hook to show a window if none is visible when command-tabbing to my app.